# Mounting ext4 partition in wsl leaves me with a blank drive after reboot

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

1. Mount ext4 partition as per [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk).

   ```
   wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 --partition 1 --type ext4
   ```
2. Create a file:

   ```
   cd /mnt/wsl
   touch testfile
   la
   ```

   Displays:

   ```
   resolv.conf  testfile
   ```
3. Reboot windows
4. Open Ubuntu again
5. [optional mounting will produce the same following output]
6. Look for the previously created file:

   ```
   cd /mnt/wsl
   la
   ```

   Shows only:

   ```
   resolv.conf
   ```

No `testfile` anymore. Please help, is it supposed to work like that?

Comment: Sounds unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?  Did that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

> is it supposed to work like that?

Well, yes.  The path you are using, `/mnt/wsl` is not the mount point for the drive itself.

`/mnt/wsl` is a [Tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/tmpfs.html) mount created by WSL itself that is shared among all WSL2 distributions.  As such:

- Files placed in it are available to *all* WSL2 distributions
- It is ephemeral.  Tmpfs filesystems live in memory and are not persisted to long-term storage.  When you reboot (or `wsl --shutdown`), anything in there will be lost.

However, if `wsl --mount` is working correctly, then you should see a message something like:

> `The disk \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 was successfully mounted under the name 'PHYSICALDRIVE2p1'. The mountpoint can be found under the path pointed to by the automount setting (default: /mnt/wsl)`

That may have thrown you off, but note that it says **under** (not *in*).  The mount point itself should be:

```
/mnt/wsl/PHYSICALDRIVE2p1
```

If you aren't seeing that drive (or another similarly named drive), then something failed during the mount.

If you place a file in *that* directory/mountpoint, then it should persist across reboots.

Note that you will need to remount the drive with `wsl --mount` after every reboot or `wsl --shutdown`.